# Test for query variable exists AND ALSO is set to a particular value?

Tags: php

I want to check if a query variable exists or not. Then I would do something based on that query value. If it exists and is true, do something. If it doesn't exist or is false, do something else such as show a 404 page.

e.g If the url was `domain.com?konami=true`

```
if (condition) {
    //something
} else {
    //show404
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works best:

```
$konami = $_GET['konami'];

if($konami == "true")
{
    echo 'Hello World!';
}
else
{
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
}
```

Comment: No it won't work best :) If you don't hand over the `?konami` parameter in your URL, then it doesn't exist and you'll get a `Undefined index` when assigning it to `$konami`. Set the PHP debugging/error reporting to on and you'll see.

Answer (score 8):

OPs question is a bit unclear. If you assume that he wants to check that `konami` is a `$_GET` parameter and that it has the value of `"true"` do:

```
if (isset($_GET["konami"]) === true && $_GET["konami"] === "true") {
    // something
} else {
    // show 404
}
```

The problem with the current accepted answer (by Cameron) is that it's lacking the `isset` check (which is unforgivable, it is objectively wrong). The problem of the highest voted answer (by Jan Hancic) is that it lacks the `=== "true"` check (which is debatable, it depends on how your interpret the question).

Note that `&&` is a lazy-and, meaning that if the first part is false, the second part will never be evaluated, which prevents the `"Undefined index"` warning. So the order of the statements is important.

Also note that `$a === true` is not the same as `$a === "true"`. The first compares a boolean whereas the second compares a string.

If you do weak comparison `$a == true` you are checking for truthy-ness.

Many values are truthy, like the string `"true"`, the number `1`, and the string `"foo"`.
Examples of falsy values are: empty string `""`, the number `0` and `null`.

```
"true" == true;   // true
"foo" == true;    // true
1 == true;        // true
"" == true;       // false
0 == true;        // false
null == true;     // false

"true" === true;  // false
"true" === false; // false
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use `isset(..) === true` vs `isset(..)` or is that style preference?

Comment: That is style preference. You can chose to disallow `!isset()` which looks a lot like `isset()`, so explicitly requiring `=== true` or `=== false` is something to consider.

Comment: Nah, I prefer `(isset($_GET["konami"]) === true) === true`.  You know, just to make it extra clear. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There is a little confusion around what value should be tested. Do you want to test the `konami` parameter for being `true` in the sense of boolean, i.e. you want to test `konami` parameter for being *truthy*, or do you want to test if it has string value equal to `"true"`? Or do you want to test `konami` parameter for *any* value in general?

I guess what is wanted here is to test `konami` for a given string value, `"true"` in this case, and for being set at the same time. In this case, **this is perfectly enough:**

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
...
if ($_GET['konami'] == "true")
    ...
```

This is enough, because if the `$_GET['konami']` is unset, it cannot be equal to any string value except for `""`. Using `===` is not neccessary since you know that `$_GET['konami']` is string.

Note that I turn off the `E_NOTICE` which someone may not like - but these type of "notices" are normally fine in many programming languages and you won't miss anything if you disable them. If you don't, you have to make your code unecessarily complex like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['konami']) && $_GET['konami'] == "true")
```

Do you really want to complicate your code with this, or rather make it simple and ignore the notices like `Undefinex index`? It's up to you.

Problems with other answers as you mentioned:

- @Jan Hancic answer: it tests for `true`, not `"true"`.
- @Cameron answer: might be simplified and he didn't mention the necessity of disabling `E_NOTICE`.
- @Frits van Campen's answer: too complex to my taste, unnecessary test for `=== true`

Answer (score 3):

Umm this?

```
if (isset($_GET['konami']) === true) {
    // something
} else {
    //show 404
}
```

Comment: @Gordon: The `true` is tested against `isset()`, so it *will* work.

Comment: Only problem with this is it works with any query value so false would also work as long as the query is konami

Comment: @Cameron he did say if it exists, not what value it has :)

Comment: Yeh but I also said based on that query being true :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
if(isset($_GET['konami']) && $_GET['konami'] != 'false') {
     //something
} else {
     // 404
}
```

Answer (score 1):

quick and simple.

```
$konami = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'konami', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) or die();
```

ref:

[filter flags](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php)

[filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this code. In this code checked two conditions by one if condition that is $konami contains value and $konami contains 'true'.

```
$konami = $_GET['konami'];
if( ($konami) && ($konami == "true")){
/*enter you true statement code */
}else {
/* enter your false statement code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$konami = false;
if(isset($_GET['konami'])){
    $konami = $_GET['konami'];
}

if($konami == "true"){
    echo 'Hello World!';
}
else{
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
}
```

In this case you'll always have `$konami` defined and - if set - filled with the value of your GET-parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$variable) { 

     //the variable is null
     die("error, $variable is null"); 
}else{

     //the variable is set, your code here.
    $db->query("....");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest and shortest way of doing it:

```
if($konami != null){ echo $konami; } else { header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'); }
```